# nesting ajax post in json get

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

```
function test() {
    $.getJSON("/Home/GetAp", function (result) {
        $.each(result, function () {
            if (this.is_disabled == "False") {
                var a = $("#MainDiv")
                            .append('<div id="imagewrap"><img id="infobutton" src="/Content/information%20icon.png" /></div>')
                            .val(this.id);
            } else if (this.is_disabled == "True") {
                var a = $("#MainDiv")
                            .append('<div id="imagewrap"><img id="infobutton2" src="/Content/information%20icon.png" /></div>')
                            .val(this.id);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        })
    })
}
```

How would I nest and ajax function be able to POST the a.val() so that when a user clicks on any $("#infobutton") they will be able to use the val of that button which would be an id specific to that button

```
$("#infobutton").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: "/Home/setID",
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: this.id }),
        success: function (result) {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: what is `val(...)` call supposed to do on a `div` wrapper?

Comment: The `if...else if ...` part only to add a `2` to the id?

Comment: the `each` loop adds elements, potentially with duplicate `id`s

Answer (score 0):

Do not make your logic depend on duplicate `id`s of DOM elements, use `class` instead.

Use event delegation to register event handlers for elements that exist at the time of event registration and for elements that will be created later.

```
.append('<div id="imagewrap"><img class="infobutton" src="/Content/information%20icon.png" /></div>')

$(document).on("click",".infobutton",function () {
  $.ajax({
    ...
  });
});
```

Comment: Tried this, however when I check the value of the id in the method setID, it shows id as null

Comment: "check the value of the id in the method setID" - what does it even mean?

Answer (score 0):

No need to nest ajax call. Just ensure click events bind to new elements appended and get the id in click event handler. Similar example (without ajax call)

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

$(document).on('click', '.info', function(e) { alert("clicked div # " +  $(e.target).text()); });

setTimeout(function(){ $("#d1").append("<div class='info'>Click info 1.</div>"); }, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){ $("#d1").append("<div class='info'>Click info 2.</div>"); }, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){ $("#d1").append("<div class='info'>Click info 3.</div>"); }, 3000);
});

<div id="d1">

</div>
```

Let me know if you need more details or example with ajax call.

For id you can use

```
$(document).on('click', '.info', function(e) { alert("clicked div # " +  e.target.id); });
```